Detect /OpenAction in a PDF with Ghostscript
I have a pdf with a Pages dictionary like this

    << /Type /Pages /Kids [
    5 0 R
    142 0 R
    225 0 R
    296 0 R
    302 0 R
    308 0 R
    314 0 R
    4 0 R
    336 0 R
    ] /Count 9
    >>
    endobj
    341 0 obj
    << /Type /Outlines /Count 1 /First 342 0 R /Last 342 0 R >>
    endobj
    1 0 obj
    <</Type /Catalog /Pages 3 0 R
    /Outlines 341 0 R
    /OpenAction [4 0 R /XYZ null null null]
    /PageLabels<<
    /Nums [0 <<
    /S /D
    >>]
    >>


Because of this the PDF is always opened on page 8 instead of the first page.
I figured out that I can reset this to the first page by just adding this in a postscript file and use that to modify the pdf
[/Page 1 /DOCVIEW pdfmark
I was wondering if it is possible to detect if a PDF has an /OpenAction
I was playing with an example I found in one of the ps files that is included when installing Ghostscript. So far I maneged to make this
    /PDFContext << >> .PDFInit def
    (D:\\Test\\test.pdf) (r) file PDFContext .PDFStream
    
    PDFContext .PDFInfo
    
    dup /Title knownoget { (Title: ) print write-doc-string () = flush } if
    dup /Author knownoget { (Author: ) print write-doc-string () = flush } if
    dup /Subject knownoget { (Subject: ) print write-doc-string () = flush } if
    dup /Keywords knownoget { (Keywords: ) print write-doc-string () = flush } if
    dup /Creator knownoget { (Creator: ) print write-doc-string () = flush } if
    dup /Producer knownoget { (Producer: ) print write-doc-string () = flush } if
    dup /CreationDate knownoget { (CreationDate: ) print write-doc-string () = flush } if
    dup /ModDate knownoget { (ModDate: ) print write-doc-string () = flush } if
    
    (Pages: ) print dup /NumPages get = flush
    
    /NumPages get 0 1 3 -1 roll 1 sub
    {
        dup
        PDFContext exch .PDFPageInfoExt exch
        ( - page: ) print 1 add =print ( - ) print
    
        dup /MediaBox knownoget
        {
            /MediaBox exch def 
            (left ) print MediaBox 0 get =print
            (, top ) print MediaBox 1 get =print
            (, width ) print MediaBox 2 get =print
            (, height ) print MediaBox 3 get =print
        } 
        { 
            (left 0, top 0, width 0, height 0) print
        } ifelse
        dup /Rotate knownoget
        { 
            (, rotate ) print =print
        }
        {
            (, rotate 0) print
        } ifelse
        (, annotations ) print
        dup /Annots knownoget
        {
            (yes) print
        }
        {
            (no) print
        } ifelse
        (\n) print
    } for flush
    
    PDFContext .PDFClose

This gives me al kind of information about the PDF but I can't figure out how to display if there are any /OpenAction 's in a PDF

That looks like pdfinfo.ps, you can get essentially the same information using -dPDFINFO at the command line. There is no way, currently, to extract arbitrary information, the only information you get is what we currently offer. You could extract more information, look in ghostpdl/psi/zpdfops.c at around line 715 for the zPDFinfo operator. By the way, that's a page tree, not a Pages dictionary, and the OpenAction is in the Catalog dictionary, not the Pages tree.

At the moment I solved it by using QPDF, in the past I have written a C# wrapper for that (https://github.com/Sicos1977/QPdfNet). It has an option to dump the PDF structure as a JSON file and that way I can detect if the PDF file has an open action and only modify the PDF's that has one.... I use Ghostscript to reset the viewed page to page 1 with this --> [/Page 1 /DOCVIEW pdfmark
